# How to get the total number of positive, neutral and negative tweets in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a new SQL developer and I am trying to write a query that will retrieve the total number of positive, negative and neutral tweets in the database. The result should look like the following:

> PositivesCount --- NeutralCount --- NegativeCount
>
> 500 ---  ---  ---  ---  --- 700 ---  ---  ---  ---  800

The schema for the tables involved in this query:

```
T_TweetSentiment Table: Id, TweetId, SentimentLabel, TypeId
T_Tweet Table: Id, TweetText
```

The T_TweetSentiment table contains three different sentiment labels; positive, negative and neutral. I would like to retrieve the total number of positive tweets, neutral tweets and negative tweets as illustrated above. **So could you please tell me how I can get the desired result?**

Here's the query I have but it is not working:

```
SELECT  MAX(CASE WHEN ts.SentimentLabel = 'Positive' THEN COUNT(ts.SentimentLabel) ELSE NULL END) AS PositivesCount, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN ts.SentimentLabel = 'Neutral'  THEN COUNT(ts.SentimentLabel) ELSE NULL END) AS NeutralsCount, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN ts.SentimentLabel = 'Negative' THEN COUNT(ts.SentimentLabel) ELSE NULL END) AS NegativeCount
FROM            dbo.T_TweetSentiment AS ts INNER JOIN
                         dbo.T_Tweet AS t ON ts.TweetId = t.Id
WHERE    ts.TypeId = 6
```

Comment: Remove MAX may be it will give correct result

Comment: Just dont get MAX(). Your query seems fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ts.SentimentLabel = 'Positive' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PositivesCount, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN ts.SentimentLabel = 'Neutral'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NeutralsCount, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN ts.SentimentLabel = 'Negative' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NegativeCount
FROM            dbo.T_TweetSentiment AS ts INNER JOIN
                         dbo.T_Tweet AS t ON ts.TweetId = t.Id
WHERE    ts.TypeId = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), SentimentLabel 
FROM SentimentLabel
GROUP BY SentimentLabel
```

Comment: Several differences: (1) this produces one row for each SentimentLabel instead of all counts in one row, (2) this omits counts for SentimentLabels that are not present, so a row for e.g. 'Negative' goes missing if there are no such items.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need `T_tweet` for this.  The `JOIN` seems unnecessary:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ts.SentimentLabel = 'Positive' THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) as PositiveCount, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN ts.SentimentLabel = 'Neutral' THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) as NeutralCount, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN ts.SentimentLabel = 'Negative' THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) as NegativeCount
FROM dbo.T_TweetSentiment ts
WHERE ts.TypeId = 6;
```

The only reason you would need the join is if you had `TweetId`s in `T_TweetSentiment` that are not in the tweets table.  That seems unlikely (and would be a sign of an issue with the data design).